# Laravel 5.6 symlink issues, 404 Not Found, but path actually exists

Tags: laravel, storage, symlink

I recently deployed my Laravel application to a shared hosting server with ssh access, on my local machine every thing worked perfectly.
but the server is returning the following error:

> failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not
>   found)

for the images stored in laravel_directory/storage/app/public/ 
i have successfully created symbolic link to public_html/storage by running

> ln -sfv /home/dtruxpgw/repositories/SoukElfalah/storage/app/public/
>   storage

from the public_html directory 
i had also tried both

> ln -s /home/dtruxpgw/repositories/SoukElfalah/storage/app/public  /home/dtruxpgw/public_html/storage
>
> ln -s /home/dtruxpgw/repositories/SoukElfalah/storage/app/public  /home/dtruxpgw/public_html

i have run also

> php artisan storage:link

and

> chmod 775 -R storage

when i run

> ls -la /home/dtruxpgw/public_html/storage

i get

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 dtruxpgw dtruxpgw 59 Feb 27 09:04
>   /home/dtruxpgw/public_html/storage ->
>   /home/dtruxpgw/repositories/SoukElfalah/storage/app/public/
>   in the cPanel the storage file exist and linked to laravel_directory/storage/app/public/ 
>   here it is the html code

`<img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="{{$img_name?asset('/storage/images/thumbs/'.$img_name) : asset('/storage/images/thumbs/default.png')}}"  alt="{{$img_name}}">`

i have been stacked here for two days now, any help i would really appreciate it 
thank you in advance .

[image: the error indicating the image not found but it exist here]
[image: the storage symbolic link successfully created]

Answer (score 0):

You missed one thing is that you can't access the file system from the storage folder directly as you have written above. If you want to access it publicly upload your documents in public directory.

You can only access files from the storage folder through route only.

Comment: If you want to display any uploaded files into web upload files into the public directory and if you want to protect your file from direct access upload file into storage directory.

Comment: did you checked for the link in browser?You need to check and confirm it from browser first.

Comment: @NarayanSharma that what i meant to do,  upload the files into the laravel storage directory to protect them,  and then accessing them by creating a simlink from the public_html. sorry but i didn't understand what should i do to fix this

Comment: @AmitKumar in the browser it is not working, but it may be because it is not declared in the routes/web.php

Comment: @harounbest if you want to keep your file into storage it won't display into the browser. What you can do is put hyperlink with test "download" and once you click on that it will go to specific routes and download from there.

Comment: @NarayanSharma   i am trying to understand why it not working, since the symlink is correctly set and it works fine on the local server

Comment: No its not that, because you have created a symbolic link for the storage it is not necessesary to declare a route. Please check the permission of softlink file

Answer (score 0):

Move the thumbs folder with the images into `public/img` and remove the symlink. It makes no sense to do it like this.. Whatever is to be public should be in the public why should you store images into the storage folder?

Comment: i followed the laravel documentation on this, now i am trying to understand why it not working, since the symlink is correctly set and it works fine on the local server